# Accessing IIS site folder from Managed windows service

Tags: windows, iis, service, directory, managed

I have a managed service that receives files from users and I process the files and create audio
 files and xml files. I want to put the generated files from my service to a directory in Webserver
(IIS) so that I can generate a link and users could download the generated files from web. Can anyone tell me how can I acheive it ( generating link is where I am stuck ). I am not sure how can I get the directory of the IIS ( there are some examples on the web to get the IIS directory... ). My question is it a good practice to get the IIS directory and copy over the generated file to a predetermined directory in a IIS site folder and generate link to that folder and send the links to the user ? can anyone please tell me a best practice to do this ? Will there be a security issue if I access a IIS site folder from windows service problem ? ( for example, Access violation  ) ?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking - you just need FSO, in order to gain access to file system on server. File Scripting Object FSO.
If you use JScript - then this will give folder postion:  Server.MapPath("\database\file.txt");
and PHP: dirname(**FILE**) . '\database\x.html';
And you need to make the ISS folders availble using Sharing and Security on folder
Mike

Comment: I can't use any scripting langugages, it is supposed to run on a server machine as service. I need to access the IIS on a remote/local machine and navigate to a predetermined directory on a site ( in IIS site folder eg. www.myiis.com/public/ )  and copy the files that I generate to the directory ( in this case "c:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\mysite\\public" ).